# Asking for password when pushing to gitlab?

Tags: git, bash, ssh, gitlab, vpn

I have a number of commits on my laptop and I am trying to push these to gitlab through a ShrewSoft VPN. However, every time I try to push the code I am asked for a password in my git bash. I have tried using my VPN password but it just throws an error. I added my SSH key in yesterday and it was all working fine but today it is not working and i'm not too sure why!!

Any ideas on what the password should be, and why I am asked for it in the first place?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The password is the gitlab password, look at the remote_url,

```
git config --get remote.origin.url
```

If it's of the type

```
git@github.com:jcjohnson/neural-style.git
```

Then you should check your local ssh key if it's in the right location :
https://help.github.com/articles/checking-for-existing-ssh-keys/

If the url is of the type

```
https://github.com/jcjohnson/neural-style.git
```

You should set your global user and password in git

https://help.github.com/articles/why-is-git-always-asking-for-my-password/

Comment: That's helped, thank you! I just added a new SSH key and it worked!

Comment: OP asks about gitlab. Even when OP marks this as the answer, this response is pointing to github documentation. Not gitlab.

Answer (score 0):

My issue wasn't ssh but that I was trying to push up my code but it saw that there was a README and wanted me to pull that first but it was having conflicts over it. I got the error:

```
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

And when pulling `git pull origin main`

```
* branch            main       -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

So I used the command `git pull origin main --allow-unrelated-histories` then `git push --set-upstream origin main` and it worked. Everything is up to date. I have the readme file and my code has been pushed up and no password required.

I also made sure my origin and source were set to the ssh url as to not get the username and password request `git@gitlab.com:username/project-app.git`. To see what yours are set to use `git remote -v`.

Hope that helps you like it did me.